# What happens when an indexed field is updated?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY `post` (`title`,`type`),
  KEY `score` (`score`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

about 95% of the queries to the table are reads

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE title = ?
AND type = ?
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Of the remaining 5% of the queries to the table, about 99% of them are updates to the score column

```
UPDATE posts
SET score = ?
WHERE title = ?
AND type = ?
```

And the remaining queries are inserts

```
INSERT INTO posts (title, type, score) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

I'm concerned of the slow speed of updating the indexed score field.

- What exactly happens when I run the update statement and the indexed `score` field is updated?
- Is there a way I can estimate the big O of this operation?
- Is `score` reindexed for every single row during an update?
- During this update are reads to the row placed in a queue, or does the query read the old `score`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Logically at least, if the score value for a row changes, then the entry for the row with the old value is deleted from the index and the entry with the new value is inserted (or vice versa).  This can be a bit more complicated if the update can be rolled back (so the changes have to be undone).
2. On average, this is about as complex as one insert and one delete operation on the index.
3. No; databases try to minimize the effort expended.  Occasionally, the removal or insert operation will require more dramatic actions in the index, such as node splitting or merging, but only when necessary, not for every row.
4. During the update, what happens may depend on isolation levels and the detailed internals of InnoDB.  Of those, I'm not sure.